# How to extract any variable as raster in tiff format from HDF5 file

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, hdf5, hdf

I have HDF5 file of precipitation in which I Can see the Groups and Datasets which are present in the HDF5 file using code as given. and snapshot of the Groups and Datasets is also shown in figure. I want to get any variable from the Group or the Datasets as raster in tiff format. Or I want to get the pixel values of any variable using some coordinates in csv file. Please Help.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)      
library(tiff)
library(ncdf4)
library(hdf5r)
library(BiocManager)
BiocManager::install("rhdf5")
library(rhdf5)
setwd("C:\\users\\administrator\\desktop\\files_for_mam_iqra\\HDF_daily\\")
a=h5file("C:\\users\\administrator\\desktop\\files_for_mam_iqra\\HDF_daily\\3B-DAY.GPM.DPRGMI.CORRAGD.20190907-S000000-E235959.250.V06A.hdf5")
list.groups(a)
list.datasets(a)
list.attributes(a)
```

[List of Groups and Datasets in the HDF5 file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXJ5F.jpg)

Comment: Can you load the data using `brick( )` command?

Comment: No sir, I do not know how to load the data using brick command. Please help

Comment: You can follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58859724/6123824. Just in place of .nc use .hdf5